# MapKit showUserLocation is not showing blue location marker

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

I have setup a custom mapView and display it full screen on my view controller. When the mapView is initialized, it checks for location authorization and if granted turns `showsUserLocation = true`

I can po in my console that this flag is hit after authorization and turns to true, and the mapView will run my centerViewOnUserLocation() method correctly, but I still cannot see the blue dot on the map for location. I am testing on my iPhone and not simulator. Here are some code examples:

View Controller

```
    private lazy var mapView: EVMapView = {
        let result: EVMapView = EVMapView()
        view.addSubview(result)
        result.delegate = self
        EVConstraintHelper.anchor(view: result, options: .classic)
        return result
    }()
```

Custom MapView

```
class EVMapView: MKMapView, EVLocationProtocol {
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        checkLocationServices()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func checkLocationServices() {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            setupLocationManager()
            checkLocationAuth()
        } else {
            print("Auth Denied")
        }
    }

    func setupLocationManager() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }

    func checkLocationAuth() {
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .authorizedWhenInUse, .authorizedAlways:
            showsUserLocation = true
            centerViewOnUserLocation()
        case .denied:
            print("Auth Denied")
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted:
            print("Auth Restricted")
        @unknown default:
            print("Unkown default selected in \(#function)")
        }
    }

    func centerViewOnUserLocation() {
        guard let coordinate = locationManager?.location?.coordinate else { return }
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan.init(latitudeDelta: 2, longitudeDelta: 2)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: coordinate, span: span)
        setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}
```

I have setup the plist Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description messages and am not sure what else it would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... I used custom placemark annotations for the mapView which removed default annotations. Technically the blue current location marker is a default annotation, so it was removed as well.